# XSLT sort and group child segments and duplicate parent

Tags: xslt

I have an xml with this structure:

```
<Order>
    <Top>
    </Top>
    <Body>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>1</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>1</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>3</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>3</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>2</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>2</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
    </Body>
</Order>
```

I need to sort and group Line by Ref/PO, and then duplicate the parent nodes for each group of Line, like in the example below.

```
<Order>
    <Top>
    </Top>
    <Body>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>1</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>1</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
    </Body>
</Order>
<Order>
    <Top>
    </Top>
    <Body>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>2</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>2</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
    </Body>
</Order>
<Order>
    <Top>
    </Top>
    <Body>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>3</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Ref>
                <PO>3</PO>
            </Ref>
        </Line>
    </Body>
</Order>
```

How can this be done? I have looked for similar questions without finding any exact match, so apologize if I have overlooked something. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming at least XSLT 2 where you have `for-each-group` you can use it to group and sort and then you simply have to reconstruct the strucuture

```
  <xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Line" group-by="Ref/PO">
          <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(current-grouping-key())"/>
          <xsl:copy select="../..">
              <xsl:copy-of select="* except Body"/>
              <Body>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </Body>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVK/1 has full working example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Line" group-by="Ref/PO">
          <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(current-grouping-key())"/>
          <xsl:copy select="../..">
              <xsl:copy-of select="* except Body"/>
              <Body>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </Body>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using XSLT 3 (but the use of `xsl:copy select` unique to XSLT 3 could be avoided for XSLT 2 with `xsl:element`), for instance

```
  <xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Line" group-by="Ref/PO">
          <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(current-grouping-key())"/>
          <xsl:element name="{name(../..)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(../..)}">
              <xsl:copy-of select="../../(* except Body)"/>
              <Body>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </Body>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB31

Comment: Thank you! This is xslt 2, so how can I achieve it without xsl:copy select?

Comment: @Sally, I have edited the answer to replace the use of  `xsl:copy-of select` with the use of `xsl:element` and the required adaption of relative paths (`xsl:copy select` changes the context node, `xsl:element` doesn't).

Comment: It looks like xslt 2 doesn't work either, so is it possible to do this in xslt 1?

Comment: Grouping and sorting is also possible in XSLT 1, https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm is a book with a chapter (chapter 9) dedicated to that so start with such a book or use any article on grouping in XSLT 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Body">
<xsl:for-each-group select="Line" group-by="Ref/PO">
  <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:element name="order">
          <xsl:element name="top"></xsl:element>
          <Body>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </Body>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
```

xslt 2.0